# How to cast a boolean into a number in App Inventor?

Tags: app-inventor

When I toggle a switch in App Inventor, a number must be sent in Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).

The problem is the following:
[image]

and I want to use the value inside a call to BLE:
[image]

The boolean is correct, the value sent is correct if it is set to a number. How to cast a boolean to a number then on AppInventor ? Any ideas ?

Comment: if true set variable to 1, else 0. Send variable to BLE.

Comment: That's what I have finally done. I use then an enum in C++ for it to cast to it boolean explicitly.